# can't access resource plugin

Tags: zend-framework

I have included plugin  `SecurityCheck.php (Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck) in bootstrap.php`. its giving error -> `Call to undefined method Zend_Application::getResource() in Bootstrap.php` on line 9. Below is my code.

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
 protected function _initPlugins()
    {

       $bootstrap = $this->getApplication();

        $bootstrap->bootstrap('frontcontroller');

        $front = $bootstrap->getResource('frontcontroller');

        $front->registerPlugin(new Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck());
    }
}
```

How to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
protected function _initPlugins() {
    $this->bootstrap('frontController')->getResource('frontController')->registerPlugin(new Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck());

}
```

C of frontcontroller should be captial.

Comment: thanks beginner, done................................................. but now its giving error -> Class 'Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck' not found .I have included this plugin in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\bin\zendtest\application\plugins